# Eclipse Java EE plugin

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, plugins

I want an Eclipse Java EE plugin which I can install directly from Eclipse.

I searched about it on Google and found some ones but couldn't figure out how to download them directly from Eclipse.

One plugin I found was WTP but couldn't find the location of the WTP repository that I can enter in the Eclipse's Software Update tool.

I am using Eclipse 3.4.2 (Ganymede)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I warmly suggest to install [Eclipse IDE for Java **EE** developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/galileosr1) which already includes the [Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and much more (see [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages) for a full comparison).

As an alternative, you can download a zip of the Web Tools from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) or install it [via Update Manager](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) using this URL:

**http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/**

Answer (score 1):

If you have Eclipse Galileo you should go to `Help > Install New Software`. Then the list of available sites to install updates will appear. You should add the WTP plug-in to this list, for example.

To do this, click on `Add` and enter the name and location (you can get this from the WTP site). Then, select this plug-in and click on `Finish`. That's it and it's valid to all plug-ins.

Comment: I know this already. The problem is that I couldn't find the location of that WTP that I can enter in the eclipse.
Please read the Q carefully.

Answer (score 1):

when you are searching do a comprehensive search http:// in eclipse

Google search the repository containing Java EE WTP

Install the new software in your IDE, restart your IDE, right click under the project explorer view, select new, the option for creating a dynamic web project should now be available. I did it using the luna version of eclipse which dose not have the default and now have the option.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
help---install new software--type http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse
```

And go from there