# No "JPA Project" in Eclipse file menu

Tags: eclipse, jpa, project

In my eclipse installation (Kepler, SR 1) there is no "JPA Project" under File >> New >> ...
I checked the installed software list, whether I miss something, but that didn't help either. Can anybody give me a hint or point me to some documentation - my google search revealed nothing.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Java EE plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216007/eclipse-java-ee-plugin)

Comment: I have - on purpose - Java SE. I am working only on fat client applications. So, Java EE is not installed, and if possible I don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to switch to [STS](https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all)! Ever since, everything is fine.